# how do i use php echo to print quotes with the variable

Tags: php, escaping, echo

i need qoutes to echo with the variables below, how do i accomplish that? ive tried escaping with \, but its not working

```
var name = "<?php echo "$_SESSION['name']"; ?>"
 var p_name = "<?php echo "$_SESSION['p_name']"; ?>"
```

Apparently  declaring a js variable requires quotes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use json_encode

```
var name = <?php echo json_encode ($_SESSION['name']); ?>;
var p_name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['p_name']); ?>;
```

That will add the quotes for you and has the benefit of also:

- turning php arrays into js arrays
- escaping any `'` or `"` in the variables you are trying to echo for you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, declaring a string in javascript requires quotes. Like most (if not all) other programming languages.

You can't just chuck a quotation mark in the middle of your echo statement and expect it to work. Why are you double quoting? Just put the quotes outside the php block.

```
var name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>";
var p_name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['p_name']; ?>";
```